# VBA Replace String gives Date

Tags: vba, replace, dataformat

I Would like to use replace funktion, but the return Value gives me a date instead of a string.

The Value is "5 bis 10" (5 to 10)
I want to return a string "5 - 10"
but it always gives me 10th May ...

here is the code I am using

.Range("D5") = CStr(Replace(CStr(.Range("D5")), "bis", "-"))

even with CStr (convert to string ) its not working ...

someone got an Idea ?

Comment: Change the cell's formatting type to text

Comment: Oh wow ... I was sure I did that at the beginning but now it works ... sometimes I am just stupid ... Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using of `.Range("D5").NumberFormat = "@"` before and after replacig.

Answer (score 0):

Change the cell's formatting type to text

worked ... I havent given the cell a format bevore so it was changing to date.

after formatting type to text it stays with text now ...

Thanks to Warcupine